# Confusion between bases (not alkali) and other -OH containing compounds

Tags: acid-base

Since some bases are not alkaline, we can't check whether they give $\ce{OH-}$ ions or not. Ethanol also has a $\ce{-OH}$ group. Why isn't it a base?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).